# How to get all the data of an ajax data into django without using request.post

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to get the data part of an ajax request into django as a dictionary without using request.post['name']

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "getAppointments",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,   //I want to get this data as a dictionary in django
        context: document.body,
    }).done(function(data) {

        alert("Successfully Edited");

    }).fail(function(returnedText) {

       window.alert("An error has occurred. Check log for details"+returnedText.responseText);
       console.log(returnedText.responseText);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client-size (your ajax request), and server-size (django) are two separate entities. Thus, you will have to parse the data coming into your `getAppointments` route like any other request body.

Regardless, `request.POST` in django is already a dictionary-like object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

Answer (score 0):

Stringify your JSON data and then receive it with `json.loads()` method in your Django view.

```
# Ajax
dataType: 'json',
data: {'my_dict': JSON.stringify(data)}

# views.py
my_dict = json.loads(request.POST.get('my_dict'))
```